# Changing the functionality of get;set; keywords

Tags: c#, .net

In order to avoid coding I implemented a dictionary to store the properties values:

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public Person Boss { get; set; }
    int i = -1;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Boss = new Person() { Name = "The Boss" };
        People = new List<Person>();

        while (++i < 10)
        {
            People.Add(new Person() { Name = $"Person {i}" });
        }

        Update();
    }

    private async void Update()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Boss.Name = $"The Boss {++i}";

        Update();
    }
}

public class Person : Model
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
}


public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> properties;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Model()
    {
        properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    protected T GetProperty<T>([CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        if(properties.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)properties[key];
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    protected void SetProperty<T>(T newvalue, [CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        properties[key] = newvalue;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(key);
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

}
```

As you see if the functionality of the get and the set in the Person Model to just use:

```
public string Name { get;set;}
```

would be really great to simplify code. Is that possible in someway? might be in C# 7?

Comment: Yes, that would be really great. Now, what is your **actual question?**

Comment: If your goal is simply to reduce the amount of written code you're actually asking for code generation. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: I would prefer want to override what the keyword get and set do

Comment: Firstly im shocked some up voted this . Secondly I'll try to verify are you asking. Is it a good practice to encapsulate the get set logic in your base class based on last stack frame ?

Comment: Maybe [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriated for that kind of questions.

Comment: @JNS probably not, nope. As I see it, this code is just an example of the actual code. Also the question is rather unclear IMO :/ Aside from that the question asks about a specific issue, which is the domain of Stack Overflow and not Code Review.

Comment: @eranotzap If I understand well the default get;set; stores a value somewhere, so why I cannot manage that by myself?

Comment: `{ get; set; }` is already a shortcut for the more verbose property structure. You cannot change how it behaves. And it is a bad idea to store the properties in a dictionary compared to having actual backing fields.

Comment: and what exactly do {get;set;} because I do not really know where stores the data.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello: You don't need to know. *That's the whole point.* If you want control over these implementation details, then don't use *auto-implemented* properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of options for reducing boilerplate code have been given to you. But if you insist on solving this problem by changing how automatic getters and setters work, then you're simply not going to be able to do that.

> If I understand well the default get;set; stores a value somewhere, so why I cannot manage that by myself?

So write your own custom getters and setters and use your own custom backing field. That's exactly what they're there for. Again, the other options given to you are there to reduce the boilerplate code, but at the end of the day, you *still* have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` using custom accessors and a backing field, because that is additional logic that falls outside the scope of an auto-implemented property.

Comment: The idea of my question was reflexionate that C# have to improve all this matter because is apps everyday coding, not complaining how to solve it. might be asking uservoice to add another keword like defineget:.... Thanks

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello: That is no different than what PostSharp already does.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with the help of AOP (aspect oriented programming) today.

E.g. with [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged), code looks like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes but it is not the point, I can do by myself creating an app that changes the get; and the set; before compiling but is not what I am asking.

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello It’s really your only option though.